# SQL Insert records in between characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to ask something, I'm working on generating an excel containing records from table.

Now, I have records in a column ex. `123450000`

The customer wants the data to be `12345-0000`

So in my select statement, every 5th of the column, there should be a dash in between

If the record has only 5 characters, then no "-" will be placed

I'm using SQL Server database for this.

Thanks :)

Comment: assuming those numbers are in an int-type field, the answer is you DON'T change the database. This is a client-side/display problem.

Comment: If this is a matter of formatting, it shouldn't be done in the database. Instead, this should be done in the presentation layer.

Comment: This is some sort of ID or order number field that no one plans on doing any math with?

Comment: How many dashes max in a field? Unlimited?

Comment: @MarcB I suspect he want to add the dashes when selecting the data from SQL Server to Excel.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the reply, I'm sorry for not providing a complete info, this is upon querying the column.

@JoachimIsaksson yes, that's right. upon selecting the field, there should be dashes in between.

Comment: FYI, it is also bad to do it then sadly, since the DBMS has to execute the presentation. Although I don't see much issue with it in your case.

Comment: Is there anyway you could change the formatting of the column in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT STUFF('12345000',6,7,'-0000');
```

Comment: Wow, This works! I never knew that there is a keyword STUFF. Though it will modify the end of the records and add the -0000, I just need to place the - though

Comment: just got some easy trick if all the data has 0000 ending it would work great

Answer (score 0):

This function should help;

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION dashify(@indata VARCHAR(MAX)) RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @breakat INT = 5
  WHILE @breakat < LEN(@indata) 
  BEGIN
    SET @indata = STUFF(@indata, @breakat+1, 0, '-');
    SET @breakat = @breakat + 6
  END
  RETURN @indata;
END;
//

SELECT dbo.dashify('12345678901234') //

> 12345-67890-1234
```